# Can't create RestTemplate() instance from spring-web

Tags: java, spring

I am using tomcat web application and rest webservice
when I insert data I get exception !

My class CustomerProxy:

```
package com.rayanen.java.se.cmsd.proxy;

import com.rayanen.java.se.cmsd.dto.CustomerDTO;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@Component
public class CustomerProxy implements ICustomerProxy{



    @Override
    public void insertCustomer(CustomerDTO customerDTO) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

        String headerValue = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestHeaderMap().get("cookie");
        requestHeaders.add("Cookie", headerValue);

        HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity(customerDTO, requestHeaders);
        ResponseEntity response = restTemplate.exchange(
                "http://localhost:8080/ws/customer/insert",
                HttpMethod.POST,
                requestEntity,
                CustomerDTO.class);
        /*return response.getBody();*/
    }
}
```

class CustomerRestController :

```
package com.rayanen.java.se.cmsd.ws;

import com.rayanen.java.se.cmsd.dto.CustomerDTO;
import com.rayanen.java.se.cmsd.exceptions.*;
import com.rayanen.java.se.cmsd.facade.facadeimpl.CustomerFacade;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/customer")
public class CustomerRestController {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerFacade customerFacade;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/insert")
    ResponseEntity insert(@RequestBody CustomerDTO customerDTO){
        try {
            customerFacade.save(customerDTO);
        } catch (StoreFailedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CustomerIDDuplicateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (EmailNotValidException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CustomerIDNotValidExeption customerIDNotValidExeption) {
            customerIDNotValidExeption.printStackTrace();
        } catch (LastNameNotValidException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NameNotValidException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

class CustomerBean :

```
package com.rayanen.java.se.cmsd.webui;

import com.rayanen.java.se.cmsd.dto.CustomerDTO;
import com.rayanen.java.se.cmsd.exceptions.*;
import com.rayanen.java.se.cmsd.facade.facadeimpl.CustomerFacade;
import com.rayanen.java.se.cmsd.proxy.ICustomerProxy;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Component
@Scope("view")
public class CustomerBean implements Serializable{


    private CustomerDTO customerDTO = new CustomerDTO();
    private String lable;

    @Autowired
    private CustomerFacade customerFacade;

    @Autowired
    private ICustomerProxy iCustomerProxy;

    public String getLable() {
        return lable;
    }

    public void setLable(String lable) {
        this.lable = lable;
    }

    public CustomerDTO getCustomerDTO() {
        return customerDTO;
    }

    public void setCustomerDTO(CustomerDTO customerDTO) {
        this.customerDTO = customerDTO;
    }

    public void insert(ActionEvent actionEvent){
        lable = customerDTO.getName() + "; " + customerDTO.getLastName();
        iCustomerProxy.insertCustomer(customerDTO);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Added Successfully", ""));

    }



}
```

and the Exeption after inserting data that I debug and Find out Exception is for this :

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
```

> 20-Nov-2017 23:06:04.211 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-5]
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute
>   /customer/insert.xhtml @43,134
>   actionListener="#{customerBean.insert}":
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/core/KotlinDetector  javax.el.ELException:
>   /customer/insert.xhtml @43,134
>   actionListener="#{customerBean.insert}":
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/core/KotlinDetector   at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:111)
>     at
>   javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
>     at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   com.rayanen.java.se.cmsd.webui.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:30)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/core/KotlinDetector   at
>   org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.registerWellKnownModulesIfAvailable(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:766)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.configure(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:619)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:602)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:59)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:67)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.(RestTemplate.java:171)
>     at
>   com.rayanen.java.se.cmsd.proxy.CustomerProxy.insertCustomer(CustomerProxy.java:22)
>     at
>   com.rayanen.java.se.cmsd.webui.CustomerBean.insert(CustomerBean.java:48)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)   at
>   org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
>     ... 34 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.core.KotlinDetector   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
>     ... 49 more

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The Fuuny part is "org.springframework.core.KotlinDetector" is for spring-core that i did not use it in any part of my CODE !!!!

Comment: Something used it. It doesn't need to be your code. Include `spring-core` as a dependency.

Comment: no , nothing used it , and I tried to add spring-core dependency but i didn't know the context.xml for spring-core so My project couldn't startup

Comment: The exception tells that something uses it, your objections don't change that fact. You're going to need that `spring-core`.

Comment: how can i search the usage of that in intellij and prove it ?

Comment: and could you plz say the xml of spring-core

Comment: Oh you're not going to find the name of the class written anywhere. It's being searched for at `TagMethodExpression:111` like the stacktrace says. Probably to check for Kotlin vs. JavaBeans handling of the expression. I'm not going to "say the xml of spring-core" because that doesn't make any sense. Besides, I prefer annotation config over xml config. You're going to need `spring-core`, and you're going to have to do some reading to understand how to configure it. Luckily for you there is a lot of documentation available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was for my other dependencies version
I changed them and problem solved

Comment: This solution worked for me. Changed the spring-core version and it worked.

Comment: changed from 5.0.2 to 5.2.3

Answer (score 2):

Yup, as @Kayaman pointed out in comments, adding spring core dependency should solves it.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```